# Red colors food and impact on stool colors

Tags: stomach, stools

Does eating pink ginger with sushi and after pomegranate seeds transform the poo into red or a physician should be consulted if the red color is see again in the stool ?

Answer (score 3):

[According to the Mayo Clinic](https://www.mayoclinic.org/stool-color/expert-answers/faq-20058080), the following can turn your stool red:

> Red food coloring, beets, cranberries, tomato juice or soup, red
>   gelatin or drink mixes.

A quick google search for "pomegranate red stool" shows several anecdotal results, but nothing that looks like a reputable source.

Anyone who is concerned about blood in their stool should see a doctor. However, if the red color consistently appears to be linked to dietary intake (stool is only red after eating pomegranates, for example), then the chances of having a bleed are low.

[The test to see if there is blood in the stool](https://www.healthline.com/health/hemoccult) is very quick and easy and can be done by a primary care doctor or in the emergency room, or even at home. It involves a rectal exam, followed by using a small amount of reagent to test the stool.

Comment: if the patient next day saw a regular color stool(brown color). What does that mean ?

Comment: It would make it less likely that there was a bleed causing the red stool, but it wouldn't rule it out. If the stool is always red after eating pomegranates, and always goes back to normal in a day, then that would be pretty good evidence that it was caused by the pomegranates, but the only way to be sure is to see a doctor.